# How to insert/delete/update a table without locking it out

Tags: postgresql, locking

Scenario: I have a table that gets accessed multiple times a day.

Users update/delete/insert/select from this table, sometimes when someone is doing a combination of 2 or more of those things at the same time, it locks up the table and any attempt to access it crashes whatever we use to access that table.

Is there a lock setting that I can use?

I'm curious to see how others handle this situation.

**Edit #1:** For my most recent lockup, update and select statements are involved. No deletes or inserts.

Comment: DML statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`) will **not** "lock the table". You need to provide more details on what **exactly** you are doing. **[edit]** your question. Do **NOT**  put code into comments

Comment: If someone does an update and someone else does a delete at the same time, this does not lock the table?

Comment: No it does not lock the **table**. If the update and the delete are done on the **same row**, then the delete is blocked for that **row** until the transaction doing the update is finished. But other statements that either just select or try to change a different row are not affected. And a "plain" select (one without a `for update`) is never blocked by DELETE, UPDATE or INSERT statements